# In Revelation 22 is it twelve manner of fruits per month or one fruit per month for twelve months?

Tags: revelation, apocalyptic

Revelation 22:2 ( KJV)

> 2 In the midst of the street of it, and on either side of the river, was there the tree of life, which bare twelve manner of fruits, and yielded her fruit every month:  and the leaves of the tree were for the healing of the nations.

Trying to find out whether these are  twelve different  fruits per month or  just one fruit per month for twelve months?

Comment: The first mention of fruit is in the plural καρπους, but the second is in the singular καρπον (Stephens 1550). 'Each month yielding the fruit of it' is the literal rendering (EGNT). So I see it as being one fruit each month with an annual total of twelve, myself.

Comment: @NigelJ,thought as much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The original Greek of Revelation 22.2 reads as follows:

> καὶ τοῦ ποταμοῦ ἐντεῦθεν καὶ ἐκεῖθεν ξύλον ζωῆς ποιοῦν καρποὺς δώδεκα, κατὰ μῆνα ἕκαστον ἀποδιδοῦν τὸν καρπὸν αὐτοῦ

So the key phrase is ποιοῦν καρποὺς δώδεκα, “making twelve fruits”. By itself this could mean anything. It could be 12 fruits per month as per the OP; it could be 12 fruits spread over a year; or it could be 12 fruits as an unqualified total. In this last case we would not be able to specify any particular time frame. We simply have a count of fruit and nothing else.

But of course the phrase is not by itself. The next phrase is κατὰ μῆνα ἕκαστον ἀποδιδοῦν τὸν καρπὸν αὐτοῦ, “according to each month giving its fruit.” When we put the two phrases together the likely picture is of a twelve month cycle. The fruit has the sense of harvest, and the tree will produce a harvest every month, twelve harvests a year. This would of course be in contrast to a typical orchardist’s experience of one annual crop. So in this pictorial way John is wanting us to imagine a tree that is always productive, always bearing fruit no matter the season.

For the sake of completeness it’s worth noting a second interpretive issue regarding the “twelve fruit”. The English translations are divided over two options:

1. “bearing fruit twelve times.” This reading interprets “fruit” as the
   generic produce of the tree, and “twelve” is the count. Thus the
   fruit will be the same each month. The NIV adopts this
   interpretation: “bearing twelve crops of fruit.” See also the GNB
   and the NASB footnote.
2. “bearing twelve kinds of fruit.” This reading interprets twelve as
       applying to different categories of fruit. For instance J B Phillips
       translates “bearing twelve fruits, a different kind for each month.”
       See also the KJV, NASB and RSV.

Given the differences in the reputable versions, we should be cautious. But my personal view is that the first option fits better with the overall picture John is creating. He’s not pointing to different kinds of fruit. The tree in view is “the tree of life”, the tree whose fruit is life. This is a clear reference back to Genesis 2. So we have one main fruit and the number twelve is intended to emphasise the constancy of that fruit. No matter the season, the month, the time, the tree is producing its fruit of eternal life.

Answer (score 1):

Seeking a literal answer to the 12 manner of fruit...as in the leaves of the tree are for the healing of the nation....have searched this through and wondered if possibly this was also like a parable. Perhaps very possibly this is not literal produce type fruit, as in.." Oranges, apples, bananas, pineapple, coconut, etc, as in the literal sense.
PERHAPS it's metaphorical for how we live the kingdom life in the kingdom and before
It is the LEAVES of the tree that are for the healing of the nations. Now, while there have been many food related miracles in Scriptures, point to ponder, we can also look at the account of the 'fruit' of the spirit; 12 mentioned in Galatians 5:22-24
'the fruits of the Spirit is love, joy, peace, patience, kindness, goodness, generosity,gentleness, faithfulness, modesty self-control, chastity."

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Rev 22:2  In the midst of the street of it, and on either side of the river, was there the tree of life, which bare twelve manner of fruits, and yielded ***her fruit*** every month: and the leaves of the tree were for the healing of the nations.

"fruit" is in the singular so we know only one type of fruit is produced in a month then a new fruit is produced the next month. If 12 different fruits appeared each month the word would have to be plural but it is singular.